# Apache Bench and POST data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apachebench

i am trying to use apache bench to load test a create action in my rails application but ab doesn't appear to be sending the POST data - though it does correctly submit a POST and not a GET request.

this is the command i run:

```
ab -n 1 -p post -v 4 "http://oz01.zappos.net/registrations"
```

and this is the contents of the post file:

```
authenticity_token=M18KXwSOuIVbDPZOVQy5h8aSGoU159V9S5uV2lpsAI0
```

the rails logs show a POST request coming through but don't show any parameters being posted:

```
Started POST "/registrations" for 10.66.210.70 at Thu Sep 09 17:48:06 -0700 2010
  Processing by RegistrationsController#create as */*
Rendered registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (14.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 24ms (Views: 14.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

whereas a POST request coming from a browser results in this log entry:

```
Started POST "/registrations" for 192.168.66.20 at Thu Sep 09 17:49:47 -0700 2010
  Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"submit"=>"true", "authenticity_token"=>"AfNG0UoTbJXnxke2725efhYAoi3ogddMC7Uqu5mAui0=", "utf8"=>"\342\234\223", "registration"=>{"city"=>"", "address"=>"", "name"=>"", "zip"=>"", "optin"=>"0", "state"=>"", "email"=>""}}
Rendered registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (13.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 24ms (Views: 14.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

and finally, this is what ab logs for the request:

```
---
POST /registrations HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: ApacheBench/2.0.40-dev
Host: oz01.zappos.net
Accept: */*
Content-length: 63
Content-type: text/plain


---
```

why is it not picking up the post data?

if the "post" file is not there then i get an error message saying it can't find the file so i know at very least it is finding the file...

Comment: I have a nearly exact problem except this time with a 150k file that ab only appears to spit 80k of it at my script which sits there blocking waiting for more IO due to the content-length.  Any luck on your side?

Answer (score 13):

Maybe you need the -T option as stated in man ab:-

```
ab -n 1 -p post -v 4 -T application/x-www-form-urlencoded "http://oz01.zappos.net/registrations"
```

I tested with Django and it seem that Django don't really care about the content type header (it displayed the POSTed content whether I used -T or not) but Rails maybe want it.

Comment: I have a similar issue with `ab` even with the `-T` option, I don't think that's it.

Comment: Same issue, and this worked for me after fixing a typo in the content type. Fixed the answer.

Comment: I was providing the content type header to -T, which was my issue `'Content-Type:application/json'` instead of just `application/json`

Answer (score 9):

Old question, but for the sake of anyone else who searches SO for this, here's how I got it to work.

Make EXTRA sure your post file is properly URL encoded with no extra non-printing characters or anything at the end.  The most error-free way is just create it with code.  I used some python to create mine:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> outfile = open('post.data', 'w')
>>> params = ({ 'auth_token': 'somelongstringthatendswithanequalssign=' })
>>> encoded = urllib.urlencode(params)
>>> outfile.write(encoded)
>>> outfile.close()
```

Example output:

```
auth_token=somelongstringthatendswithanequalssign%3D
```

Comment: You are missing the load testing part ;)

Comment: You are right.  You still need to actually run ab, using your new, properly encoded post.data file, of course.  Just generating the post.data file does little to test your web server (or whatever it is...)

Comment: In Python 3.8 I had to: `from urllib.parse import urlencode` and call as: `encoded = urlencode(params)`.