# Make a POST request using ab (apache benchmarking) on a django server

Tags: django, post, apachebench

I'm trying to make a HTTP POST request using [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) to a form built with django.

I'm using the following line:

```
ab -n 10 -C csrftoken=my_token -p ab_file.data -T application/x-www-form-urlencoded http://localhost:8000/
```

My `ab_file.data` looks like this:

```
url=my_encoded_url&csrfmiddlewaretoken=my_token
```

It always returns a `403` status code.

When I use `curl` using the same parameters, it works. The curl line:

```
curl -X POST -d "url=my_encoded_url&csrfmiddlewaretoken=my_token" --cookie "csrftoken=my_token" http://localhost:8000/
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@jacobm654321,

for sure, the best thing to do is encode the URL programmatically. But my problem wasn't that. My problem is that the file containing the post data had a blank line at end of file. EditorConfig put it there. After remove that blank line, everything worked well.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: For vim users, `vi postFile`, `:set binary noeol`, `:wq` to remove the end-of-line ('\n');

Answer (score 29):

File must have a properly url-encode data. If you url-encode manually, it is too easy to have typos like blanks wrong encodes.   Best do it programmatically.
See an another answer: [Apache Bench and POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9624289/4797528)
on how to use Python to create such file  ( ex: post.data)

Then use:
 `ab -T 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'  -n 10 -p post.data http://localhost:8080/`

Comment: Hello, Is it possible to specify post data within the command instead of the file just like in curl?

Answer (score 10):

When using ab, the entire contents of the data file must be wrapped onto a single line - it fails silently if it's normally expanded JSON. So a post from a data file that works fine with curl will fail with ab until you do this.

Tip: If using Atom or VSCode, select all and hit Cmd-J to wrap everything to one line.